# How can I create a transparent video from transparent images?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a set of transparent images, where each one represents a frame of a video. I know that I can overlay them on top of another video using `-i %d.png`. What I want to be able to do is turn them into a transparent video ahead of time, and then later be able to overlay that transparent video onto another video. I've tried just doing `-i %d.png trans.mov` and then overlaying `trans.mov` on top of another video, but it doesn't seem like `trans.mov` is actually transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an encoder that supports transparency/alpha channel. You can view a list of encoders with `ffmpeg -h encoders` and get further details with `ffmpeg -h encoder=<encoder name>`, such as `ffmpeg -h encoder=qtrle`. Then refer to the `Supported pixel formats` line: if has as "`a`" in the supported pixel format name, such as `rgba`, then it supports alpha. See a general list of pixel formats with `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.

The simplest solution is to mux the PNG files into MOV:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %d.png -c copy output.mov
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my Mac running OS Ventura. I get an output.mov file but I can't open it with Quicktime nor with any other software.